# Django: Is there anyway to specify a django url path for a template of the item currently being iterated in a forloop

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a simple unordered list of entries that have been iterated over a Django forloop like this.

```
<ul>
  {% for entry in entries %}
  <li>{{ entry }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

However, I wanted to make all of the listed items in the forloop to be links to a template html file. Which brings the question, is there a way to format my code to where the URL pathway can take the name of the entry to link it to the desired template for it? Something like this.

```
    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %} 
            <li><a href="{% url 'encyclopedia/{{ entry }}' %}">{{ entry }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

obviously this code doesn't work, but is there something similar that I can do?

Heres my urls.py and views.py for more information.

urls.py

```
path("<str:TITLE>", views.TITLE, name="TITLE")
```

views.py

```
def TITLE(request, TITLE):
   # util.markdownify(f"{TITLE}.html", f"{TITLE}.md") 
   return render(request, f"encyclopedia/{TITLE}.html")
```

Comment: Do yo need to know how to get a link that sends you to the specific page of, let's say, ItemA or ItemB or ItemC? If able, post also your model so you can give more details

Answer (score 0):

I try to give you an answer, I don't know your models so you have to adapt the code probably.
urls.py

```
path("<str:title>", views.title, name="title") #I suggest to use lowercase letters
```

template

```
<ul>
        {% for entry in entries %} 
            <li><a href="{% url 'encyclopedia' title=entry.title %}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
   </ul>
```

Now you can create an encyclopedia template with your title view

views.py

```
def title(request, title):
   entry = YourModel.objects.get(title=title)
   return render(request, encyclopedia.html", {'entry ': entry })
```

And your encyclopedia.html file could be something like this:
encyclopedia.html

```
{{entry.title}} //or whatever you need in your template
```